# Shipping Location based on IP (Geolocation)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to limit the Countries in the Shippiment to another address and Billing (Checkout) to the User IP Address location. Say the user is in USA I only want this country to show as a option under the dropdown country list or disable the option of changing the country. How would I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First of all to make geolocation work properly go to WooCommerce > Status and check `MaxMind GeoIP database` option, if there is red checkmark follow the provided instructions to download the database.

Then you can add this code to your theme (at the bottom of `functions.php`) or add it as a plugin or [code snippet](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-easily-add-custom-code-in-wordpress-without-breaking-your-site/) as changes in theme might get lost when you update it.

```
function wpse_287199_woo_checkout_country( $fields ) {
    $geoData = WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip();
    $countries = WC()->countries->get_countries();

    $fields['billing']['billing_country'] = array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'label'     => __('Country', 'woocommerce'),
        'options' => array(
            $geoData['country'] => $countries[$geoData['country']]
        ),
        'class' => array(
            'form-row-wide',
            'address-field',
            'update_totals_on_change'
        )
    );

    $fields['shipping']['shipping_country'] = array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'label'     => __('Country', 'woocommerce'),
        'options' => array(
            $geoData['country'] => $countries[$geoData['country']]
        ),
        'class' => array(
            'form-row-wide',
            'address-field',
            'update_totals_on_change'
        )
    );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'wpse_287199_woo_checkout_country' );
```

This code checks the client's IP geolocation and determines his country then it is used for shipping and billing as an only option.